# How To Extend Parameters on the URL in KohanaPHP?

Tags: php, url, parameters, kohana, kohana-3

How do I pass extra parameters in the URL to KohanaPHP (version 3.1+) like so...

```
http://example.com/blog/edit/4000/3200
```

...where "blog" is the blog.php in the controllers folder, "edit" is a controller method, 4000 is parameter 1 which I can use for who wants to edit the record, and 3200 is parameter 2 which I can use for the record ID?

I get the blog and edit parts. The problem is the 4000 and 3200. When I run that URL, I get an error: "404 - Unable to find a route match blog/edit/4000/3200"

Am I forced to have to do something unusual with the .htaccess file, or pass the parameters as query params after a question mark?

Comment: `.htaccess`. PHP can't intercept requests, so you need Apache (or another webserver) to help direct them to the appropriate PHP file.

Comment: @Blender. Do you know the KohanaPHP MVC framework? It already uses an .htaccess file, which directs all traffic to index.php for processing. So the question is a Kohana framework question, not a generic PHP question.

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out your question. Can you make it a bit more explicit, as in it's current state, it's pretty vague.

Comment: Huh? By default, the way I see it, Kohana lets me detect and route the "blog" and "edit" in the URL. But for 4000 and 3200, it won't let me. Someone really experienced with Kohana will likely know this answer. I may have to subclass the Front Controller or something.

Comment: As you aren't getting many views (only nine), I'm not sure how to help. Whenever I worked with web frameworks (I used Flask), I had to specify the type of the input whenever I used it within the URL. It seems that your application isn't recognizing integers, but strings work. I've never used this framework before, so I'm to really able to help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This explains what to do:

http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/routing

But essentially, I need to edit the application\bootstrap.php file and change this:

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'welcome',
        'action'     => 'index'
    ));
```

to this:

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<param1>)(/<param2>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'welcome',
        'action'     => 'index'
    ));
```

And now in my blog.php controller file, I can now pass 2 parameters into the "action_edit" class method like so:

```
public function action_edit() {
  $sParam1 = $this->request->param('param1');
  $sParam2 = $this->request->param('param2');
  $this->response->body('param1=' . $sParam1 . ' param2=' . $sParam2);
}
```

Comment: Please dont use arg list in controller's methods. It will be deprecated in v3.2. Use `$this->request->param('param1')` instead. Another thing is in regex. If your param1&param2 are integer, define them as integer: `Route::set('defaults', '...', array('param1' => '\d+', 'param2' => '\d+'));`. Also, why do you want to pass userID via URI? Usually you can get to user data from session (or something like `Auth::instance()->get_user()`)?

Comment: And remove param1 and param2 from `defaults()` call. `$this->request->param()` returns NULL for empty segments.

Comment: @blakaveron "Why user ID via URL?" It was a hypothetical, yet pathetic, example I could come up with in my mind at the time alotted. Just overlook it, please. The focus is really is about passing URL parameters.

Comment: @biakaveron I made your other recommended changes. Thank you. As for param1 and param2 being integer -- I need them to be flexible and store any data type. I can validate their values in the controller action, instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need a route like this in your bootstrap.php:

```
Route::set('blog_edit', 'blog/edit/<param1>(/<param2>)')
        array(
            'param1' => '[[:digit:]]{1,}',
            'param2' => '[[:digit:]]{1,}',
        ))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'blog',
        'action'     => 'edit',
    ));
```

**Note:** the "`()`" makes `param2` optional.

In your controller you can access the parameters as method arguments **or** via the Request object:

```
class Controller_Blog
{
    public function action_edit($param1, $param2)
    {
        // or
        $param1 = $this->request->param('param1');
        $param2 = $this->request->param('param2');
        // [...]
    }
}
```

*I haven't tested this code but it should be very close to what you need.*

Referenced from "[Kohana PHP 3.0 (KO3) Tutorial Part 6](http://www.dealtaker.com/blog/2010/03/03/kohana-php-3-0-ko3-tutorial-part-6/)"