# Hyphens in URLs with Kohana PHP Framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, frameworks, apache2, kohana

This is an Apache .htaccess question.

In Kohana PHP Framework (I'm on 3.1), it doesn't appear that they support hyphens in URLs for the controller or action, which are the first 2 URL parameters after the domain, as in:

http://example.com/controller/action

OR

http://example.com/blogs/edit-article

Is there a way I can make my .htaccess file so that I can strip hyphens (dashes) out of the controller and action slots, but not the other slots? Here's my current .htaccess file:

```
Options All +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -Multiviews

# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$   application/views/assets/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/application/views/assets/.*

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404646#answer-8751122

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Kohana 3.1's boostrap.php for my project, I had to add this above the default route:

```
Route::set(
    'custom',
    function($uri) {
        $uri = rtrim($uri, '/');
        $asParts = @ explode('/',$uri);
        $controller = @ $asParts[0];
        $action = @ $asParts[1];
        $param1 = @ $asParts[2];
        $param2 = @ $asParts[3];
        $param3 = @ $asParts[4];
        $controller = str_replace('-','_',$controller);
        $action = str_replace('-','_',$action);
        $controller = (empty($controller)) ? 'home' : $controller;
        $action = (empty($action)) ? 'index' : $action;
        return array(
            'controller' => $controller,
            'action' => $action,
            'param1' => $param1,
            'param2' => $param2,
            'param3' => $param3
        );
    }
);
```

This lets me do the following things:

- A dash in the action becomes a function in the controller class with an underscore. So, 'add-new' becomes 'action_add_new()'.
- A dash in the controller becomes a subfolder because controller underscores naturally in kohana mean a subfolder. So, because of the str_replace() function above on the controller, if I have a controller of 'test1-test2', Kohana goes looking for a controller folder 'test1', and then a controller file 'test2.php'. But the catch is this, your test2.php needs to begin as 'class Controller_Test1_Test2 extends Controller {'.
- And then I'm also able to pass 3 SEO-friendly parameters after the URL without having to use the more ugly ?p1=blah&p2=blah&p3=blah query param technique. This is [explained more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608846/how-to-extend-parameters-on-the-url-in-kohanaphp).